# What is a good way for writing a function to measure another function in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir

I'm new to elixir, I'm trying to find something similar to Python's ContextManager.

### Problem:

I have a bunch of functions and I want to add latency metric around them.

Now we have:

```
def method_1 do
  ...
end

def method_2 do
  ...
end

... more methods
```

I'd like to have:

```
def method_1 do
  start = System.monotonic_time()
  ...
  end = System.monotonic_time()
  emit_metric(end-start)
end

def method_2 do
  start = System.monotonic_time()
  ...
  end = System.monotonic_time()
  emit_metric(end-start)
end

... more methods
```

Now code duplication is a problem

```
  start = System.monotonic_time()
  ...
  end = System.monotonic_time()
  emit_metric(end-start)
```

So what is a better way to avoid code duplication in this case? I like the [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#implementing-a-context-manager-as-a-class) idea in python. But now sure how I can achieve something similar in Elixir, thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang/Elixir this is done through higher-order functions, take a look at [BEAM telemetry](https://github.com/beam-telemetry/telemetry). It is an Erlang and Elixir library/standard for collecting metrics and instrumenting your code - it is widely adopted by Pheonix, Ecto, cowboy and other libraries. Specifically, you'd be interested in `:telemetry.span/3` function as it emits start time and duration measurements by default:

```
def some_function(args) do
  :telemetry.span([:my_app, :my_function], %{metadata: "Some data"}, fn ->
    result = do_some_work(args)
    {result, %{more_metadata: "Some data here"}}
  end)
end

def do_some_work(args) # actual work goes here
```

And then, in some other are of your code you listen to those events and log them/send them to APM:

```
:telemetry.attach_many(
  "test-telemetry", 
  [[:my_app, :my_function, :start], 
   [:my_app, :my_function, :stop], 
   [:my_app, :my_function, :exception]],
  fn event, measurements, metadata, config -> 
    # Handle the actual event.
  end)
  nil
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing to python context manager would be to use higher order functions, i.e. functions taking a function as argument.
So you could have something like:

```
def measure(fun) do
  start = System.monotonic_time()
  result = fun.()  
  stop = System.monotonic_time()
  emit_metric(stop - start)
  result
end
```

And you could use it like:

```
measure(fn ->
  do_stuff()
  ...
end)
```

Note: there are other similar instances where you would use a context manager in python that would be done in a similar way, on the top of my head: Django has a [context manager for transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) but [Ecto uses a higher order function](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:transaction/2) for the same thing.

PS: to measure elapsed time, you probably want to use `:timer.tc/1` though:

```
def measure(fun) do
  {elapsed, result} = :timer.tc(fun)
  emit_metric(elapsed)
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a really nifty library called [Decorator](https://hexdocs.pm/decorator/readme.html) in which macros can be used to "wrap" your functions to do all sorts of things.

In your case, you could write a decorator module (thanks to @maciej-szlosarczyk for the [telemetry](https://github.com/beam-telemetry/telemetry) example):

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Measurements do
  use Decorator.Define, measure: 0

  def measure(body, context) do
    meta = Map.take(context, [:name, :module, :arity])
    quote do
      # Pass the metadata information about module/name/arity as metadata to be accessed later
      :telemetry.span([:my_app, :measurements, :function_call], unquote(meta), fn ->
        {unquote(body), %{}}
      end) 
    end
  end
end
```

You can set up a telemetry listener in your `Application.start` definition:

```elixir
:telemetry.attach_many(
  "my-app-measurements", 
  [[:my_app, :measurements, :function_call, :start], 
   [:my_app, :measurements, :function_call, :stop], 
   [:my_app, :measurements, :function_call, :exception]],
  &MyApp.MeasurementHandler.handle_telemetry/4)
  nil
)
```

Then in any module with a function call you'd like to measure, you can "decorate" the functions like so:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Domain.DoCoolStuff do
  use MyApp.Measurements
  
  @decorate measure()
  def awesome_function(a, b, c) do
    # regular function logic
  end
end
```

Although this example uses telemetry, you could just as easily print out the time difference within your decorator definition.